# Coreml's MLModel with flexible shape runs much slower than fixed shape

Tags: coreml, coremltools, onnx-coreml

Recently, I find that the mlmodel with flexible shapes runs much slower than the same mlmodel with fixed shapes.
Such as a detect mlmodel, the default input shape is 3 x 416 x 416, it takes 20ms on iphoneXS with ANE(ComputeUnitsALL) with fixed shape.
Then, I changes the mlmodel to 3 X 416... X 416... by coremltools, and I also gives the 3 x 416 x416 image as input, but it takes 60ms on iphoneXS with ANE(ComputeUnitsALL).
I am confused with this problem. Has anyone encountered the same problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: This may be because with flexible shapes, Core ML cannot pre-compute everything. But that still shouldn't make the model 3x as slow. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: I found that the flexible-shapes model running on ANE(ComputeUnitsALL) takes same time with  running on GPU(ComputeUnitsCpuAndGpu). But the fixed-shapes model running 3x faster on ANE than GPU. Maybe the model still runs on GPUandCPU, though I set the ANE configuration.

Comment: Yes, if the model runs the same time on the GPU then it's likely it's always using the GPU even though you asked for the ANE.